# How to establish SSH connection between two machines from different cloud providers?

Tags: amazon-web-services, jenkins, ssh, sap-commerce-cloud

I have one CentOS instance in AWS and another instance in Hybris Cloud.

The AWS instance is running a Jenkins Server and I want to install a slave for it in the Hybris Cloud Instance.

I have followed the steps to establish SSH connection between two machine but still can't get them to connect.

What am I missing? Is there any special SSH configuration for establishing connection between different cloud providers?

Answer (score 0):

I cant speak for Hybris, but AWS has a security group for  your EC2 instance. The security group for your AWS instance must allow port 22 from the IP address of your Hybris server (or a range of IP addresses). In addition, the host firewall on the EC2 Jenkins server must allow for this as well.

Likewise, the Hybris server must have the same ports opened up.

If you continue having issues after checking security groups and host firewalls, check the Network ACL in AWS. If you are in your default VPC and there have been no alterations, the Network ACL should allow for your use case. However if you are in a non-default VPC, whoever created it may have adjusted the Network ACL.